# On click copy a text in html

Tags: javascript

I have used the following javascript and I was able to copy the text, but I would like to add the following to be copied but it should not be visible in the html page.

```
function copy(that){
    var inp = document.createElement('input');
    document.body.appendChild(inp)
    inp.value =that.textContent
    inp.select();
    document.execCommand('copy',false);
    inp.remove();
}
```

and used the following text in the table to copy the content inside tag

`<td onclick=\"copy(this)\">yeci0192</td>";`

The above script is working,
but, I would like to add `"File="` before `"yeci0192"` but it should not be displayed in the html.
`On click File=yeci0192`
should get copied.

Comment: `inp.value = "File=" + that.textContent`

Answer (score 0):

```
function copy(that){
    var inp =document.createElement('input');
    document.body.appendChild(inp)
    inp.value = "File=" +that.textContent
    inp.select();
    document.execCommand('copy',false);
    inp.remove();
}
```

This will then just append th "File= " partot he copied string

Comment: @MisterJojo Aameer nagvenkar, Thank you very much for taking your time and answering my question. The above script works.

Comment: @MisterJojo Is it possible to copy a text like this
   <div onclick="copy(this)" value="yeci0192" >&#169;</div>

Comment: Is it possible to copy a text like this
`<div onclick="copy(this)" value="yeci0192" >&#169;</div>`
Copy the value in the div instead of the symbol given.

Answer (score 0):

is that what you are looking for ?

**[edit]** changing on Purushothaman remarks

```js
const onCopy = document.querySelector('#toCopy')

document.querySelectorAll('.toCopy').forEach(d=>
  {
  d.onclick=_=>
    {
    let copyText = 'File='+d.dataset.info
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText )

    onCopy.textContent = copyText + ' -> copied !'
    onCopy.classList.add('show')
    setTimeout(()=>{ onCopy.classList.remove('show')}, 2000);
    }
  })
```

```css
.toCopy {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .2em .3em;
  cursor:pointer;
  background-color:white;
  font-size: 2em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: .2em;
}
.toCopy:hover {
  background-color:yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#toCopy {
  display: none;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: .2em;
  padding: .2em .3em;
  position: fixed;
  top:70px;
  left:10px;
}
#toCopy.show {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="toCopy" data-info="yeci0192">&#174;</div>

<div class="toCopy" data-info="hot.coffee">&#9749;</div>


<div id="toCopy"></div>
```

Comment: I would not like yeci0192 appear on the html page instead, I would like a symbol display on the html page. If the operator click the page then the file name should be copied. Similar to the following code which displays the file name in a alert box `<div style=background-color:white; onclick=\"alert('yeci0192')\"><font size =\"2\">&#174;</font></div>`

Comment: @Purushothaman  I've changed my snippet.   Please be more explicit for your next questions.